# Reset div content based on php files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a client requesting a static page have the content of said page scroll to the bottom, and then have the content of the page switch to another php file (which simply returns html), scroll to the bottom and repeat. I've tried to accomplish this using a recursive jQuery function but everytime the function calls itself, it seems to run through the loop twice as many times as it previously went through, or the content refreshes almost immediately.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
            <p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p>
            <p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p>
            <p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p>
            <p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p>
            <p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p><p>This is dummy content.</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Slideshow (Counter) {
            var Count = Counter;
            var Pages = [   "slideshow/50_50.php",
                            "slideshow/news.php",
                            "slideshow/sponsorship.php",
                            "slideshow/standings.php",];
            var time = ($(document).height()/100)*1000;
            var height = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
            if (height <= 0) {
                height = $(window).height();
                time = 5000;
                }
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: height }, time, function() {
                $("#content").load(Pages[Count], function(){
                    Count++;
                    if (Count >= 2) {
                        Count = 0;
                        }
                    //alert("Height: "+height+"\nTime:"+time+"\nCounter:"+Counter);
                    Slideshow(Count);
                    });
                });
            };
        $(document).ready(function() {
            Slideshow(0);
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the 'Pages' array is the list of pages for content to be returned. Time and height are (supposed to be) calculated fields for the scrolling animation, with a check that if the content is smaller than the screen height the content will remain on screen for 5 seconds.

Another set of eyes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you step through the browser debugger to see how many times the Slideshow function is getting called?

Comment: Is the script being included again?

Comment: Just finished @raduation; the first iteration the function is called once, the second it is called twice, and the third time it is called 4 times. The first 3 iterations all seem to respect the time parameter in the animate. After that, it appears to call the function twice roughly every second.

Comment: @charlietfl the function calls itself close to the bottom (I believe this is what you were asking).

Comment: Where are these function calls originating?  What does the stack trace show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
$("html, body").animate(...
```

Your `Slideshow` method will then get called twice for every recursive call, leading to an explosion in calls.  Try replacing with:

```
$('body').first().animate(...
```

Comment: That's perfect @raduation - solved all the issues I was having!